# how to monitor user training for my org

Tags: administration, configuration, help

as an administrator I wanted to see what users have completed what modules in the help & training section. Is there a way to report on this or is there a special section within Help & Training to display this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by navigating to

**Setup -> Manage Users -> Training History**

Here is the documentation where it states this

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=monitoring_training_history.htm&language=en_US